# Performance for Intel's new low-voltage CPUs

Tags: laptop, cpu, battery-life

I've been laptop shopping recently, and I'm intrigued by the [Acer Timeline](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0029U1526) series. It seems to fit somewhere in between "netbook" and "power laptop" performance-wise, and is rated at 8 hours battery life.

I can't seem to find much objective info about the processor in it though: [intel SU2700](http://ark.intel.com/product.aspx?id=42004). I know that it's single-core and low-voltage, but how well does it perform? I'd expect it to fall somewhere between an Atom and a Core 2 Duo, but that's a pretty large discrepancy.

I'm interested in:

- Impressions from someone who has actually used one of these
- Links to benchmarks
- Other "objective" performance data. Stuff like "boots vanilla windows 7
  25% slower than a C2D."

**The Plot Thickens:** Looks like you can get the Timeline with either single core (Linked above) or [dual-core](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16834115593) low-voltage chips. I'm sure relative performance is

Atom < Low Voltage Solo < Low Voltage Duo < Regular Duo

but how far apart are each of these, performance-wise?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a page that shows a comparison of that processor to the Core 2 Duo.

> http://ark.intel.com/compare/40479,42004

[image: Some Additional Info]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a review of a laptop with a related processor, [the SU3500](http://www.techreport.com/articles.x/17078/1).  The conclusion is that the laptop bridges the gap between netbook and ultra-portable, but from the included benchmarks, I'd be thinking slightly faster than a netbook, but far far far below a standard Core 2 Duo laptop.